# Android Grid view with different width of column

Tags: android

I am trying to make grid view with two column but the problem is that I want to change the width of every column randomly.

I try to create it using stagger grid view but it only change the height of column and I need to change of width of column.

I am adding image what I want to make below:

[image]

Comment: You should use RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager

Comment: If you don't want a fixed column height then u should use StaggeredGridLayoutManager in recyclerView.

Comment: in this case the height of the grid item is changed but i want the height of the grid fix only want width change. Please see my image

Comment: @VishalPuri i want to fix the height of the column and change the width of column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `setSpan` method for `GridLayoutManager`. In beginning use number of columns as 4, then as per need give span to each view in GridView.

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(activity, 4);

gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup()
{
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position)
    {
        if (position == 0)
        {
          return 2;
        }
        else if(position == 1)
        {
          return 2;
        }
        else if(position == 2)
        {
        return 3;
        }
        else if(position == 3)
        {
        return 1;
        }                       
    }
 });
```

Comment: i want to only two column in one row, only the width of column will change

Comment: Yeah you will have 2 columns only. Give each view span of 2, then two columns of equal width. GIve one view span of 1 and other view span of 3 then you will have two columns in the width ratio 1:3. I have edited my post with code. Check it and tell if it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Use two or more synchronized list view will do. By 'synchronized', I mean when you swipe horizontally, both list views move accordingly.

You might checkout this [PinterestListView](https://github.com/vladexologija/PinterestListView) repo for reference.

[image]

The sole difference is that you change the orientation of the list view, from vertical to horizontal.

If you don't wish to support horizontal swipes/scrolls, use two linear layout embedded into a vertical layout, that is it!

Comment: in this case the height of the grid item is changed but i want the height of the grid fix only want width change. Please check my image first

Comment: you should read the post carefully, you need to change the orientation.

Comment: in your case height of the column is change but i do not want to change it  and i want to scroll vertical.

Comment: you need look at the source code in github, and use it as a reference. I could not see any challenges, if you want to take a look at the source code.

Comment: we do not need to use this github library this functionality is already provided by Android RecyclerView StaggeredGridLayoutManager. but i am looking for another type

Comment: you don't need to use that library at all. you never read the post! read it carefully pls.

Comment: "For reference", see this in the post?