# Staggered Grid View (Both Directions) - different cells width - vertical scroll

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

I need to make panel of some sort with a Staggered Grid behavior such in the photo attached (cells width are not the same in each cell):

[image]

I tried normal `GridView`, I tried `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` with and without a recycler view,
I've searched the internet for so long, and still hasn't found anything that gave me the suitable solution in java.

I also tried with the following answer: [LayoutManager for RecyclerView Grid with different cell width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514887/layoutmanager-for-recyclerview-grid-with-different-cell-width) and [Android Grid view with different width of column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787092/android-grid-view-with-different-width-of-column) (There are many more answers similar to this 2), but I need it to be "dynamic" and what I mean by that is that I need the cell width to be determine by it's content width and not just by it's index like in the answers attached.

Anyone knows a way to accomplish such a thing? or knows a library or a similar project with that feature?

Comment: it might, I will try it now and update you

Comment: it did, thank you, @Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout may help you.

You can use `FlexboxLayoutManager` as adapter and play with properties, all the views will wrap automatically depending on their width.

Comment: You should mark as a duplicate instead of repeating the answer from the duplicate question.